# Resize Wordpress theme header / logo

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I resize the header area in order to insert a bigger logo.  The logo height is not adjusting properly. This is a specific theme.  I will include the header code and the css code.

CSS:

```
/* =Navigation
----------------------------------------------- */

.site-content .site-navigation {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.site-content .nav-previous {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.site-content .nav-next {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
}

/* =top
----------------------------------------------- */

.topbar {
  height:40px;
  background:#302b29;
}

.top {
  background:url(images/top.png) repeat-x;
  height:117px;
}

.head {
  background:url(images/head.png) center no-repeat;
  height:117px;
}

.logo {
  padding:5px 0px;
}

h1.site-title {
  font-size:20px;
  font-family: Arial,serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#fff;
  margin:15px 0px 5px 0px 
}

h1.site-title a:link,h1.site-title a:visited {
  color:#fff;
}

h2.site-description {
  font-size:14px;
  color: #eee;
}


/* Searchform */

#searchform {
  width:260px;
  float:right;
  margin-top:8px;
}

#s {
  width:180px;
  padding:3px 5px;
  background:#4C4645;
  border:1px solid #5E5B5B;
  color:#fff;
}

#searchsubmit {
  padding:3px 10px;
  background:#800404;
  border:1px solid #A00C0C;
  margin-left:5px;
  box-shadow:none;
  color:#fff;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #540404;
}
/* TOP-MENU */

#botmenu {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#submenu {
  margin: 30px 0px;
  padding:0px 0px;
  height:50px;
}

#submenu ul {
  width: auto;
  float:left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#submenu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #222;
  font-weight:400;
}

#submenu li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
    margin: 0;
  padding: 16px 10px 16px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

#submenu li a:hover, #submenu li a:active, #submenu .current_page_item a  {
  color: #fff;
}  

#submenu li a.sf-with-ul {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#submenu li ul li a, #submenu li ul li a:link, #submenu li ul li a:visited,
#submenu li ul li ul li a, #submenu li ul li ul li a:link, #submenu li ul li ul li a:visited,
#submenu li ul li ul li ul li a, #submenu li ul li ul li ul li a:link, #submenu li ul li ul li ul li a:visited {
  color: #eee;
  width: 148px; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-top:1px solid #403837;
  position: relative;
  font-weight:400;
}

#submenu ul li ul li:first-child a,#submenu ul li ul li ul li:first-child a,#submenu ul li ul li ul li ul li:first-child a  {
  border-top:none;
}

#submenu li ul li a:hover ,#submenu li ul li ul li a:hover ,#submenu li ul li ul li ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff; 
}

#submenu li ul {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
  height: auto;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background:#302B29;
  border:1px solid #302B29;
}

#submenu li ul a {
  width: 150px;
}

#submenu li ul a:hover, #submenu li ul a:active {
}

#submenu li ul ul {
  margin: -49px 0 0 181px;
}

#submenu li:hover ul ul, #submenu li:hover ul ul ul, #submenu li.sfHover ul ul, #submenu li.sfHover ul ul ul {
  left: -999em;
}

#submenu li:hover ul, #submenu li li:hover ul, #submenu li li li:hover ul, #submenu li.sfHover ul, #submenu li li.sfHover ul, #submenu li li li.sfHover ul {
  left: auto;
  }

#submenu li:hover, #submenu li.sfHover {
  position: static;
}  

/* Layout */

#primary, #secondary{
  padding:50px 0px;
}
```

Header Code:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
  <div class="topbar">
    <div class="container_6">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="top cf ">
    <div class="container_6">
      <div class="head cf">
        <div class="logo grid_2">
          <h1><a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>/" title="<?php bloginfo('name');?>"> 
            <img style="float: left;" src="linktomylogo/newlogo1.png" alt="" width="148" height="90" /> </a>
          </h1>
          <h2 class="site-description">
            <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="botmenu" class="grid_4">
          <p><?php shailan_dropdown_menu( ); ?></p>
          <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_id' => 'submenu', 'theme_location' => 'primary','menu_id'=>'web2feel' ,'menu_class'=>'sfmenu','fallback_cb'=> 'fallbackmenu' ) ); ?>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</header><!-- #masthead .site-header -->
<div id="main" class="site-main cf">
```

I have changed a few things but it messes up the site.  The height of the image should be around 200 and not 90px.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the logo is placed inside the div with the class of `top`, and the other with a class of `head`. I've modified their CSS slightly below.

```
.top{
    background:url(images/top.png) repeat-x;
    height:200px;  /* Change the height here */
}

.head{
    background:url(images/head.png) center no-repeat;
    height:200; /* and here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked.  I had to remove the top.png image because it did not look good after making the adjustments.  The white background works well.